# How to prevent Inventory Table from reducing product quantity if Sales order is cancelled/returned?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have both an Inventory Table and Sales Table. If there is a sale, the Inventory table will automatically reduce the Product quantity. Im adding a Status column to show the sales transaction status.
So far I had to manually highlight cancelled/returned orders and input the cancelled transaction into a different table where the Inventory table will add it in to negate the inventory deduction.

I wish for it to be automatically not do the calculation if there is cancelled or returned status

I tried the IF functions but it doesnt work, im not sure if its because i added a sumif functions but it is necessary as there will be multiple sales of a similar product so i have to sum it up the total product sale and minus it from the inventory.

Another way i tried was adding an additional column, basically a duplicate quantity sold. Only difference is that i added an IF function, if it detects the status as cancelled, itll be 0, if not, then itll show the quantity ordered. Then my Inventory table will deduct from that extra quantity column. Its kind of cheesing the excel but yeah, so far im doing it that way but I wish to know the proper way to do it because this is unprofessional and unclean.

Hopefully you understood my explaination, because english is not my main speaking. Thank you

Comment: Please share the formula you shared along with some sample data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables . Please share expected result with given data.

Comment: What about something like "=if(or(A1="return",A1="Cancelled"),-1,1)" and multiply the sales value by that.